# GlassFish not recognizing a specific servlet

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, web.xml

I have a problem with a webapp I'm developing for my Uni course.

The registration to the website is managed with a servlet that I named "Register", and the user must access to said servlet through a link in the header of the website.

The problem is that, if I name my servlet "Register", GlassFish refuses to recognize it and gives me 404, but if I create a new servlet in the same package named whatever and I copy/paste the code of "Register" onto that GlassFish is fine with it and everything works. Why? What am I doing wrong?

I'd give the servlet another name but my webapp is going to be automatically inspected by some tool my professor developed, so I cannot change its name (and, frankly, I don't want to because I want to understand what is wrong with my code and prevent this error to appear again). For this project I'm using Java 8, NetBeans 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1.

EDIT: I forgot to explain that I tried linking the servlet "Register" in other pages (in the welcome file or in other "major" pages") but the result is the same: 404 if the servlet is named "Register" and everything fine if I change its name

Here's the code for header.jsp, the location of the link to the servlet that I include in every page of my website:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="header">
    <div>
        <a href="/ProgettoFPW/index.jsp"><h1>FPWriter</h1></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <c:if test="${user == null}">
            <h2 style="color: gray">Articoli/Gestione</h2>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${user != null}">
            <c:if test="${user.isAuthor() == true}">
                <a href="/ProgettoFPW/pages/articoli.jsp"><h2>I miei articoli</h2></a>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${user.isAuthor() == false}">
                <a href="/ProgettoFPW/pages/gestione.jsp"><h2>Le mie valutazioni</h2></a>
            </c:if>
        </c:if>
    </div>
    <div>
        <c:if test="${user == null}">
            <!-- this line gives me problems -->
            <a href="/ProgettoFPW/Register"><h2>Registrazione</h2></a>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${user != null}">
            <a href="/ProgettoFPW/pages/profilo.jsp"><h2>Profilo di ${user.getName()}</h2></a>
        </c:if>
        </div>
    <div>
        <c:if test="${user != null}">
            <!-- this line doesn't give me problems, even though it works just like the other one -->
            <a href="/ProgettoFPW/Logout">
                <h2>Logout</h2>
            </a>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${user == null}">
            <a href="/ProgettoFPW/pages/login.jsp">
                <h2>
                    Login
                </h2>
            </a>
        </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note, I use the same way to link the "Logout" servlet, but that gives me no problem whatsoever. That's why my only explanation of this not working is the name of the servlet.

Here's the screen capture of my webapp folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRavb.jpg

and here's my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>control.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>control.Logout</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>control.Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Could you please give me a hand? I'm truly lost here. Please let me know if my explanation lacks some information

Comment: Are there any errors in the log file when deploying?